# Power Apps - Incompatible types for sharing

Tags: powerapps

I am attempting to set an error message on a datacardvalue when the App ID selected already has an existing row in my SharePoint list.  I am getting this error message on it though.  Any ideas on how to correct this?  The App ID is a Lookup field in my Sharepoint list (looking at another list in Sharepoint).  Not sure if that's what is causing it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ045.png)

Comment: The LookUp field from sharepoint is a reference field, not a text field. So you are correct. You can either typecast the values into text, which will give problems or use the reference of the sharepoint connector as explained here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=G4pWRzzCDAM

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be that Sharepoint LookUp values are not treated as text([?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-and-SharePoint-Lookup-Columns/td-p/104168))

**Try:**

**1. A `LookUp()` instead of `Filter()`**:

```
If(
    IsBlank(Trim(DataCardValue2.Text)),
        "An App ID is Required",
    
    CountRows(
        LookUp(
            'Johanna Test List',
            'App ID' = Trim(DataCardValue2.Text),
            ID
        )
    ) > 0,
        "Duplicate ID not allowed",

    ""
)
```

**2. Added `.Value` after the Sharepoint column name**:

```
If(
    IsBlank(Trim(DataCardValue2.Text)),
        "An App ID is Required",

    CountRows(
        LookUp(
            'Johanna Test List',
            'App ID'.Value = Trim(DataCardValue2.Text), //<--Here
            ID
        )
    ) > 0,
        "Duplicate ID not allowed",

    ""
)
```

**OR:** After the LookUp results...

```
If(
    IsBlank(Trim(DataCardValue2.Text)),
        "An App ID is Required",

    CountRows(
        LookUp(
            'Johanna Test List',
            'App ID' = Trim(DataCardValue2.Text),
            ID
        ).Value                                      //<--Here
    ) > 0,
        "Duplicate ID not allowed",

    ""
)
```

Comment: Yeah, no dice.  It's not liking the .Text after the DataCardValue2.

Comment: Yeah, because you have no obvious naming convention for your PowerApps controls, I can't easily tell what types of controls exist. For Textboxes, use `txtSomething`, for Dropdowns use `ddSomething`, Comboboxes use `cmbSomething`, Buttons use `btnSomething` etc. The `.Text` I was referring to would work for a Textbox. Try `DataCardValue2.Selected.Value` (assuming this is a Dropdown).